# How to write multiple xml files within one program using ElementTree in python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I have an issue where I'm reading multiple CSV files and I need them as multiple XML files in a one to one relationship.

When I run my program each subsequent XML file contains everything from the previous file.

Like its doing an append.

I'm guessing what I need is the XML equivalent of close() or clear() or something as the tree isn't cleared between writing the XML files.

I found way to remove elements from trees but not how to clear it.

And even then I'm not sure that would work properly as the root will probably be deleted by any 'global' clear.

```
    import csv

    try:
       import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
       print("running with xml.etree", "\n")
    except ImportError:
       print("xml didn't import", "\n")


    path_0 = "C:/folder1/" 

    root = ET.Element("users")

    index = 0


    while index < 8:

       index = index + 1 

       with open(path_0+"_"+str(index)+".csv") as myfile:
           csvrows = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
           for row in csvrows:

             doc = ET.SubElement(root, "user")

             ET.SubElement(doc, "thing").text = "thing"

             tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

             tree.write(path_0+"output_file"+str(index)+".xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its a bit hacky and I'm sure its not the "right" solution but you can clear down the tree inside the 'while', outside the 'with':

```
   for user in root.findall('user'):
      root.remove(user)
```

That gets rid of all the elements and leaves you with the root, ready for the next file.